Can an employee be sued in civil court for HIPAA violation?
The question is based on a video that has been circulating on youtube. The (supposed) situation was that a man donated sperm to a sperm bank; which is supposed to legally protect the donor from child support. However someone working at a bank (or a lab) was a friend of a recipient; and revealed the donor's identity to the recipient - who (again supposedly) successfully sued the donor for child support.
Now, what I'm NOT interested in is "how legally plausible the above situation is?" (sounds like no judge would award child support in this situation, but does not matter here). BUT, for the purposes of this question, let's just assume for a second that the situation is real as described. Or, to generalize, an employee flagrantly and deliberately violated HIPAA regulations which resulted in severe monetary damages to an individual.
The victim has no federal recourse under HIPAA itself, based on my research.
However, what I want to know is, can the victim sue the employee - OR if not, the employer - under any state laws etc...? (obviously anyone can sue anyone for anything... question is whether that lawsuit has any realistic chance of succeeding in such a scenario).

You ask twice if someone "can" sue, admit that it's obvious that they can, then flip to wondering about chances of success.  Objection, calls for speculation. Voting to close as opinion based.

@MichaelHall: You could make the same argument for closing 99% of the law.se fair use questions.  I feel like there are enough cases of the form, "victim sues for damages directly caused by breaking a law which lacks explicit private right of action" that it's possible to provide an answer that is reasonably well-informed.  The answer might be something like "the courts usually decide X because of concept Y" or "the courts decide based on rule Z, which is super unpredictable." I wouldn't call such an answer opinion-based.

@Brian, pulling a couple essential phrases "question is whether that lawsuit has any realistic chance..." and "...which is super unpredictable" I stand by my opinion that an answer would be based on opinion.  Thanks for your feedback on my comment though.  If you think there's a good answer here then please go for it!  (FWIW, I share your frustration with a lot of close votes, but my peeve is with those who equate any personal relevance to a request for advice.)

The terms of the sperm donation contract would matter.

@MichaelHall - the answer I expected would be an entirely un-specilative "here's the case law for similar cases, here's results of those cases". Or in worse case "here;s a law that says you can't sue on those grounds - like HIIPA itself".

@ohwilleke - don't sperm banks all use pretty standard contracts, all of which presumably have non-disclosure of PII included? Besides, a sperm bank is just a reason the general question popped into my mind - as stated, I am interested ideally in a generic answer where "employee of a company governed by HIIPA violated the rules, resulting in serious monetary damages to victim client of the company" case. Could just as well be a medical office where employee revealed results of medical diagnosis or test result, which led to a client losing money.

@user3885 There is no such thing as a "standard contract" in this area. Also, as the question itself notes, there isn't a private cause of action for a HIPAA violation, so it would have to fit into some other state law remedy which might be context specific.

Also, a general answer under HIPPA probably isn't possible because the child's right to know who their biological parent is will in some cases override HIPPA considerations, but some other HIPPA protected information might not have a similar exception. And, the imposition of child support payments is almost surely not a valid category of damages for improper disclosure.

@ohwilleke - (1) isn't the child's right to know not applicable until age of majority for the child? (2) you're again zeroing on on irrelevant detail,  you are welcome to pick any other HIIPA example you think is more bulletproof. E.g a person losing a well paying job based on HIIPA protected info from a lab/doctor

@user3885 The details aren't irrelevant. The question you are asking doesn't have a general answer. The remedies available depend upon the specific facts and aren't the same in all cases at that level of generality.

I am not a lawyer, but my son is, and he works in civil litigation mainly on the defense side.  Some of the stories he tells are crazy, and they often result in a decent settlement for cases that seemingly have no merit.
In the situation you describe, the awarding of child support would be state dependent.  And I feel that things may change with the changing abortion laws in certain states.  Given that some states now classify unfertilized eggs as human life, it follows that a sperm donor would be liable for child support.
The likelihood that someone bring such a case is high, in my opinion, as it could result in a precedent setting decision.
The father, even if such a case does not succeed, is well within his rights to sue the employer of the person that made this disclosure.  It need not be a HIPAA violation; it could be in the contract signed at the time of sperm donation.  It could be a violation of company's policy or privacy clause.  Likely all three.
I could see a situation where child support is granted and the donation company would have to pay it along with other damages incurred by the donator as well as some punitive damages.

I'll offer Harrington v. Madison Cnty. as an example in support of this answer.  The court noted that HIPAA does not allow private right of action, but does not preclude private right of action under other statutes (in this case the Montana Health Care Information Act).  So presumably at least some states would allow such a case to move forwards.
